# Is there a custom way for implementing an object clone function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, clone

I am currently using something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, myVar):
        self.myVar = myVar
    def clone(self):
        return MyClass(self.myVar)
```

Is there a more custom (standard) way of doing this in Python, perhaps by overriding operator `__new__` or something of that sort?

I'd rather this function to be an instance function and not a class (static) function, but I'd be happy to hear any suggestion.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Please add more details about the goal of your code.

Comment: @Cardstdani: The goal is to return `x.clone()` from a function, in order to avoid the caller function being able to change the contents of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

A standardised way of doing this in Python is for the caller to call `copy.copy(obj)` or `copy.deepcopy(obj)`.

[Documentation at docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

As standard, `copy()` will result in the copied object having references to the same objects that the original did.  `deepcopy()` will result in the copied object having references to *copies* of those objects.

To illustrate:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.vals = vals

import copy
orig = Example([1, 2, 3])
shallow = copy.copy(orig)
deep = copy.deepcopy(orig)
orig.vals.append('surprise')

print(f'orig.vals: {orig.vals}')
print(f'shallow.vals: {shallow.vals}')
print(f'deep.vals: {deep.vals}')
```

results in:

```
orig.vals: [1, 2, 3, 'surprise']
shallow.vals: [1, 2, 3, 'surprise']
deep.vals: [1, 2, 3]
```

Note the difference between the shallow and the deep copy.  `shallow.vals` still pointed to the list in `orig.vals`, whereas `deep.vals` was an independent copy of that list.

Now, for your example class, this is all that is needed: you don't need to add a special method to your class.  But if you wanted cloning behaviour that was more custom, you could implement the `__copy__` and/or `__deepcopy__` methods in your class.